# how to do virtualization?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, wireless

I am newbie in vc++. I have configured my system with WDK,DDK and Visual Studio 2008. I want to implement dual functionality to my wireless hardware and i am using Vista so please help me out from here.
so just tell me which function should i use

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: You have to learn how to ask a good question first.  Start by reading Walter Oney's books.

Comment: You are too underleveled for DDKs. Do some GameDev first to level-up :P

Answer (score 6):

Advice: Forget it.

This is driver level development - so you need the DDK. It is DEFINITELY NOT something for a C++ newbie. You talk about the probably most arcane level of programming.

Do you have documentation for the hardware? If not - that is the first step.